# How did piratebay.se search engine get in Chrome as an "other search engine"

Tags: malware, chrome, darknet

I have an IT client with a user who had piratebay.se/... listed within his Chrome's (v39, 64-bit, OS X, 10.10.1) "Other Search Engine" section.

I know a user could manually add it and suspect the piratebay.se website could have offered to add it while a user was visiting there.

QUESTION
Is it probable that malware could add the piratebay.se search engine? I also removed one of the few OS X browser hijacks from this same browser at the time I discovered the piratebay listing in Chrome's "Other Search Engines."

What's the probability of an unauthorized addition of piratebay.se to a browser's search engine? I'd like to know this in order to help my client decide whether to ask the computer's users about their access to piratebay. If it's unlikely malware added the piratebay search engine, then my client will talk to users of this computer.

SIDE QUESTION
Has anyone seen or read about malware adding piratebay.se/... to Chrome or another browser's search engines? I couldn't find any postings about such an instance.

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/a/7630169/4416961

Answer (score 1):

Chrome will automatically add search engine configurations any time you visit a site that has a compatible search box. If you don't want it to be there, then remove it.

How did it get there? The user went to the pirate bay, and chrome added it.

The answer to all of your probability questions is: *not very probable given the fact that Chrome will helpfully add the search engine entry on its own for you.* It is, however, very probable that the user has been using the pirate bay site.

Comment: Thanks! I wondered if it was that straight forward. Looks like the boss is going to talk to some users.

Answer (score 0):

Various sites will offer you the option to add them as a search engine, so it may be likely that the user visited the Piratebay and just clicked to approve such a thing.

Comment: I know that's common among other sites and possible, as my original post mentioned, but my question is whether malware could have added it, especially in light of a browser hijacker in the same browser at the same time.

Comment: Oh, it definitely is a possibility, yes. I haven't seen this used, but there is no reason why it couldn't be.

Comment: I haven't seen malware do that either and couldn't find any posting about it. I know it's possible and so asked whether it's "probable" instead. It doesn't seem probable since other people online aren't complaining about it. I think my client's going to have a talk with each user of that computer.