# Pirate Bay Search Appearing in Chrome

Tags: malware, virus, chrome, search-engines

While googling some errors today I noticed I had the option to use

> the pirate bay search
>
> [image]

Now I saw a similar question posted here [How did piratebay.se search engine get in Chrome as an “other search engine”](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/76554/how-did-piratebay-se-search-engine-get-in-chrome-as-an-other-search-engine)

But my problem is different.

It only appears when I search what I was searching in the above photo, it doesn't appear for anything else, or at least I haven't found another search combination where it has appeared.

**eg**

> [image: Search One]
>
> It only appears when I use the below search.
>
> [image: Search Two]

As well, there is no extension in my chrome browser which installs this, it's just there.

> [image: Extensions]

Now the obvious answer might be, oh you visited PirateBay at some stage and that's why it's there, But I can guarantee that this system has never once been on the site, the last thing I googled which included the word Pirate was "Pirate Jokes" which, unfortunately turns up some good results.

[image]

I have scanned my system for Malware and Viruses and there's nothing.

**So -**

1. The machine is free of Malware and Viruses
2. The machine has never visited The Pirate Bay before
3. There's no Chrome Extensions for "The Prate Bay Search"
4. It only appears for certain Syntaxes

**Basically my questions are -**

1. How could that have gotten there
2. Is there anything to worry about
3. If so, what would you recommend

Thanks in advance

**Edit One:**

If i try to search using it, it will re-direct me to the piratebay

> [image: Searching]
>
> [image]

We block the website so it will never go there, but it could potentially cause issues for a network where Torrent Sites are not blocked.

**Edit Two:**

So my new question is.

Can this be a vulnerability to a users machine?

If a company or user did not have sites like that blocked and a user searched it accidentally, could they be infected with malware, I'm thinking of a JavaScript exploit or something similar as 90% of users I imagine just click "Allow" or "Okay" on pop ups.

> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackhole_exploit_kit
>
> https://heimdalsecurity.com/blog/javascript-malware-explained/
>
> [I've encountered JavaScript attack code - how do I search for information on the exploit's specifics?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/41966/ive-encountered-javascript-attack-code-how-do-i-search-for-information-on-the)

Comment: I wouldn't be worried. This is just google trying to think ahead of you (I think). I just typed the same thing into my work PC address bar and it showed up, and this computer has never been near the pirate bay, or else I would be out of a job.

Comment: @INV3NT3D That's good to know, I don't have to be worried now about Google chrome framing me haha

Comment: Haha definitely do not worry about that. But, I would still like to see the question of "how it got there" answered. Is it necessary to visit the web-page (i.e. TPB) for that search engine to be integrated into chrome? Is it possible it was integrated in a different website, and included for that reason?

Comment: @INV3NT3D according to the answer I linked it is, but it would be interesting to know where chrome scrapes that kind of information off and how it chooses to distribute it, seems like poor form on their end to try and redirect you to an illegal pirating site, I've edited the answer because it actually re-directs you to the pirate bay in order to search if you use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a Chrome feature.
Chrome is suggesting some of the search engines you've used at some point based on keywords in your search query.*

Open [chrome://settings/searchEngines](http://chrome://settings/searchEngines) to see that The Pirate Bay is there.

* You say that the device has never visited The Pirate Bay before. Did not, or just deleted it from history? I'm not sure whether deleting the history will delete all the other search engines too.

Comment: It's a company network, piratebay is blocked and not accessible at a firewall level,therefore, never visited, i can also guarantee my machine has never visited it before now. - http://imgur.com/a/hUuyt No listing of piratebay in search enginges either.

Comment: Maybe simply having the word "pirate" in your search history gets Chrome to enable TPB search engine? :P

Comment: @RyanIG Not in the search engines? Interesting.

Comment: @RyanIG I checked my home computer and TPB was in my search engine listing, it was under "T" not "S" for me though. Just FYI. Still confused as to how my work computer lists it. Maybe because I have logged into my Google account from this browser?

Comment: Oh right, I didn't notice. @INV3NT3D is right - it's The Pirate Bay on my machine too.

Comment: @SamuelShifterovich after double checking It's there alright just under T, no idea how it got there though, potentially from signing into my personal gmail account like INV3NT3D said as there where some other forums I would use at home listed there as well.

Comment: Holy crap there's a ton of "search engines" in there. I'm guessing any site you visit can register itself as a "search engine" without asking? Seems dangerous. Is there any way to clear all of these without individually deleting each one?

Answer (score 1):

It's from your search starting with the word "the", and google not having something to auto-populate. Search anything starting with "the" and keep adding words until google stops trying to guess.

Comment: And not just the Pirate Bay. I tried the same search string and got "The Business Continuity Institute search". It's matching the "the", it would seem.

Answer (score -1):

It's got to be to do with the information stored by the browser, and stored locally, despite History not having deletable data that stops it popping up.

**Go to Chrome Settings --> You and Google --> Sync and Google Services --> turn OFF Improve search suggestions.**

Here it says *"When you type in the address bar or search box, Chrome sends what you type to your default search engine to get better suggestions. This is off in Incognito."*

This comes across as very sneaky, and it is, but is probably not an attempt to breach data between searchbars. The result however is that data seems to be shared across searchbar providers, making us ask whether Piratebay itself shares its searches with Google. However, whether it is stored by Google after we turn this setting off, remains to be seen.

Comment: I tried the same search string and got "The Business Continuity Institute search". It's matching the "the", it would seem. Your speculations appear to be wrong. And nothing is being sneaky.

Comment: Sorry to hear you've had issues with the suggestion. This is probably because "Chrome Settings --> You and Google --> Sync and Google Services --> turn OFF Improve search suggestions" is not a search string, it's a toggleable option within the browser settings in Google Chrome, found by clicking the three dots at the top right of the screen.

Comment: I tried the same search string *as the OP*. There is no "the" in your menu path... If you had read the other answers, you would have seen that there is more context here. So, no, data is not shared between search providers, PirateBay is not sharing data with Google. As I say, Chrome is trying to find a suggested search source. And ultimately, this doesn't answer the question. It is speculating on how to get this behaviour to stop.